# What is the market capitalisation of the crypto exchange Binance?

Tags: corporate-finance, cryptocurrency

Cryptocurrency exchange FTX has raised USD 400 million in a Series C fundraise, helping bump up the company's valuation to $32 billion (1 Feb 2022). What is Binance company valuation? Not BNB market cap but the company's market cap.

Answer (score 0):

In their April 2022 financing round, the valuation was $4.5bn, see https://www.forbes.com/sites/stevenehrlich/2022/04/06/crypto-exchange-binanceus-raises-200-million-seed-round-at-45-billion-valuation/

Comment: That is only Binance.US, the American franchise of Binance.com

Comment: I am afraid, there is no data on that. It's a privately held company and their last financing round was years ago.